# Find max value of nested Dict with character values in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have the following Dict:

```
{'children': [{'children': [{'criteria': ['United Kingdom'],
     'name': ['3'],
     'prediction': ['0.256'],
     'weights': ['604']},
    {'criteria': ['United States'],
     'name': ['4'],
     'prediction': ['0.231'],
     'weights': ['5316']}],
   'criteria': ['United Kingdom United States'],
   'name': ['2'],
   'prediction': ['0.233'],
   'variableNames': ['Country name'],
   'weights': ['5920']},
  {'children': [{'criteria': [' Brazil Canada'],
     'name': ['6'],
     'prediction': ['0.153'],
     'weights': ['10029']},
    {'criteria': ['France Germany Spain Turkey'],
     'name': ['7'],
     'prediction': ['0.053'],
     'weights': ['1335']}],
   'criteria': [' Brazil Canada France Germany Spain Turkey'],
   'name': ['5'],
   'prediction': ['0.141'],
   'variableNames': ['Country name'],
   'weights': ['11364']}],
 'criteria': ['l 1'],
 'name': ['1'],
 'prediction': ['0.173'],
 'variableNames': ['Country name'],
 'weights': ['17284']}
```

I need to find the max & min values of of both predictions & weights, which are both character types, so ill need both to convert them to Float / int's and then find their max/min values, while iterating through all key/values.

Using some previs great questions I found out that if the values where ints that would have worked:

```
 max(test, key=lambda x: test[x]['prediction'])
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-43-e7d4b2e19f21>", line 1, in <module>
    max(test, key=lambda x: test[x]['prediction'])

  File "<ipython-input-43-e7d4b2e19f21>", line 1, in <lambda>
    max(test, key=lambda x: test[x]['prediction'])

TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

And this is as close as I got to converting the values into int/float:

```
for body in test:
     test[body]['prediction'] = float(test[body]['prediction'])
     test[body]['weights'] = int(test[body]['weights'])
```

Which throws again a similar error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need a recursive function to walk through your dict

```
def maxr(D, k):
    return max([float(D[k][0])] + [maxr(i, k) for i in D.get('children', [])])
```

output

```
>>> maxr(D, 'prediction')
0.256
```

You can define a function `minr` similarly

Answer (score 1):

If all you want is the max of a particular field, John's solution works fine, but I think it'd be more flexible to have a generator that recursively yields each dictionary.

```
def iter_children(data):
    yield data
    for child in data.get('children', []):
        for c in iter_children(child):  # if you're using Python3 "yield from" can simplify this
            yield c


print max(float(c['prediction'][0]) for c in iter_children(raw_data))
print max(int(c['weights'][0]) for c in iter_children(raw_data))
```

then it's easy to do something like get the maximum prediction only if "Brazil" is in the criteria.

```
print max(float(c['prediction'][0]) for c in iter_children(raw_data) if 'Brazil' in c['criteria'][0])
```

Comment: Thanks, but i really need a particular field :)